# What is causing this LINQ to XML Argument Exception?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to initialize an `XDocument` with data that will eventually be provided by a database.  For testing purposes, I've hard-coded the data.

```
WFEvent[] wfs = new WFEvent[] {
    new WFEvent {
        ID = new XElement("WorkflowEventID", 0),
        ParentID = new XElement("ParentID", 0),
        Active = new XElement("Active", false),
        Status = new XElement("Status", "Complete")
    },
    new WFEvent {
        ID = new XElement("WorkflowEventID", 1),
        ParentID = new XElement("ParentID", 0),
        Active = new XElement("Active", true),
        Status = new XElement("Status", "In Progress")
    },
    new WFEvent {
        ID = new XElement("WorkflowEventID", 2),
        ParentID = new XElement("ParentID", 1),
        Active = new XElement("Active", false),
        Status = new XElement("Status", "Pending")
    },
    new WFEvent {
        ID = new XElement("WorkflowEventID", 3),
        ParentID = new XElement("ParentID", 2),
        Active = new XElement("Active", false),
        Status = new XElement("Status", "Pending")
    },
    new WFEvent {
        ID = new XElement("WorkflowEventID", 4),
        ParentID = new XElement("ParentID", 3),
        Active = new XElement("Active", false),
        Status = new XElement("Status", "Pending")
    },
    new WFEvent {
        ID = new XElement("WorkflowEventID", 5),
        ParentID = new XElement("ParentID", 4),
        Active = new XElement("Active", false),
        Status = new XElement("Status", "Pending")
    },
    new WFEvent {
        ID = new XElement("WorkflowEventID", 6),
        ParentID = new XElement("ParentID", 5),
        Active = new XElement("Active", false),
        Status = new XElement("Status", "Pending")
    },
    new WFEvent {
        ID = new XElement("WorkflowEventID", 7),
        ParentID = new XElement("ParentID", 6),
        Active = new XElement("Active", false),
        Status = new XElement("Status", "Pending")
    },
    new WFEvent {
        ID = new XElement("WorkflowEventID", 8),
        ParentID = new XElement("ParentID", 7),
        Active = new XElement("Active", false),
        Status = new XElement("Status", "Pending")
    },
    new WFEvent {
        ID = new XElement("WorkflowEventID", 9),
        ParentID = new XElement("ParentID", 8),
        Active = new XElement("Active", false),
        Status = new XElement("Status", "Pending")
    },
};

XDocument xml =
    new XDocument("RatingOverview",
        new XElement("RatingRequest",
            new XElement("CreateNewRatingRequest", wfs[0].ID, wfs[0].ParentID, wfs[0].Active, wfs[0].Status)
        ),
        new XElement("Assessment",
            new XElement("NeedsAssessment", wfs[1].ID, wfs[1].ParentID, wfs[1].Active, wfs[1].Status),
            new XElement("GroupConcerns", wfs[2].ID, wfs[2].ParentID, wfs[2].Active, wfs[2].Status),
            new XElement("Recomendation", wfs[3].ID, wfs[3].ParentID, wfs[3].Active, wfs[3].Status)
        ),
        new XElement("TechnicalAssistancePlan",
            new XElement("VerifyCurrentRating", wfs[4].ID, wfs[4].ParentID, wfs[4].Active, wfs[4].Status),
            new XElement("PlanDeveloped", wfs[5].ID, wfs[5].ParentID, wfs[5].Active, wfs[5].Status),
            new XElement("ContactLog", wfs[6].ID, wfs[6].ParentID, wfs[6].Active, wfs[6].Status)
        ),
        new XElement("EnvironmentalRatingReport",
            new XElement("ERSScores", wfs[7].ID, wfs[7].ParentID, wfs[7].Active, wfs[7].Status),
            new XElement("ERSPlanDeveloped", wfs[8].ID, wfs[8].ParentID, wfs[8].Active, wfs[8].Status)
        ),
        new XElement("SubmitRequest",
            new XElement("SendToDCC", wfs[9].ID, wfs[9].ParentID, wfs[9].Active, wfs[9].Status)
        )
    );
```

I'm getting the following exception when `XDocument xml` is initialized:

"`System.ArgumentException: Non white space characters cannot be added to content.`"

Hopefully I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to spot the problem, and Google has not yielded any useful information on this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because the code you've got is basically trying to add text directly to the XML document. If you were allowed to run that code, you'd end up with this invalid XML:

```
RatingOverview 
<RatingRequest>
    ...
</RatingRequest>
...
```

The "RatingOverview" text in that invalid XML snippet is the "non white space characters" the exception is complaining about.

What you really want is this:

```
<RatingOverview>
    <RatingRequest>
        ...
    </RatingRequest>
    ...
</RatingOverview>
```

To get there, you don't have to change much. Just make sure your "RatingOverview" is also an `XElement`, not just a `string`. Try this:

```
XDocument xml =
    new XDocument(
        new XElement("RatingOverview", // <== fix here
            new XElement("RatingRequest",
                new XElement("CreateNewRatingRequest", wfs[0].ID, wfs[0].ParentID, wfs[0].Active, wfs[0].Status)
            ),
            ...
        ) // <== don't forget to add a parenthesis here
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick!  I figured it was something simple I was overlooking.